# Can HERE map tiles display road speed limits?

Tags: here-api, heremaps

I would like to know if the HERE map service allows a developer to configure the tiles to display road speeds in some way?

I see that HERE has [APIs for road speeds](https://developer.here.com/blog/getting-started-with-speed-limits-and-fleet-telematics), but I am not after fetching data, processing and drawing it myself. Rather, I have a map control in my project, and that map control uses the HERE service to fetch map tiles, and I wanted to simply have an option to fetch tiles that (also) displays speeds.

Is there such an option? I have been looking through the docs, but haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding some volatility information the Map Tile(raster) API supports only

truck restriction tiles: https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-base-truckonlytile.html

and traffic flow: https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/resource-traffic-flowtile.html

Vector Tile API supports only roads, topologies, cartos and labels - doesn't support also any speed info.

Therefore you can use only Fleet Telematics API that returns only speed limits data then push this info as markers into map, See please examples on https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/pde_speed_limits_in_view or https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/pde_speed_limits_along_route
or https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1 - there search by keyword like 'speed'

Documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/index.html - we don't have any examples for this new api.